# Sets and set operations in Sage

Tags: sage

How am I able to input this into Sage?

A = {x ∈ ℕ | x ≤ 10}

B = {a, b}

I've looked at the docs and they are not clear. I am trying to find the union and distinction between them afterwards.

Comment: What are `a` and `b`? What docs have you looked at (link please) and what improvements to them would you suggest?

Comment: This one particularly: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/sets/sage/sets/set.html   I am a novice in Sage, the examples were hard to follow. I can suggest giving a scenerio of how to find the union,distinction etc with a given set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you want.

```py
sage: A = set(0 .. 10)
sage: B = {4, 12}

sage: A.union(B)
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12}
sage: A.intersection(B)
{4}

sage: A.difference(B)
{0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
sage: A.symmetric_difference(B)
{0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12}
```